# How to create a chord in celery whose tasks are chord themselves

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to create a chord in celery whose tasks in a group are chord themselves. So the idea being - each of the individual subchords execute first and then the results of these chords are then finally used by the callback of the parent task. Here is the code that I am trying to do

-- tasks.py

```
import celery
from celery import chord

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    print "add called..."
    return x + y

@celery.task
def tsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)

@celery.task
def gr_add(x):
    print "**** gr_add called"
    c = chord(add.subtask((i,i)) for i in range(2*x, 2*x+2))
    r = c(tsum.subtask())
    return r.get(timeout=120)
```

-- and then my test-chord-chord.py file contains

```
from tasks import add, tsum, gr_add
from celery import chord

c = chord(gr_add.subtask((i,)) for i in range(2))
result = c(tsum.subtask())
print result.get(timeout=5)
```

However, this is not executing as expected. Am I doing it correctly? Is there another way of achieving the above?

Answer (score 1):

I am finally able to figure out what is the problem. Though not very sure how to go about solving it. The culprit is call to the callback in the `gr_add` above, specifically the line - `r = c(tsum.subtask())`. This will block - consequently the worker that runs this task will block. Now when I had only one worker - the above was a problem. When I started multiple workers (specifically three in this case - because original chord is creating two chords) and each only picking up one task `CELERY_PREFTCH_MULTIPLIER = 1` and `CELERY_ACKS_LATE=True`. The three workers picked up the tasks on the queue - 1st picked up first chord and is blocked now. The second picked up second chord and is blocked now. The third picked up first task of the first chord - computed, exited - unblocked. Picked up next task - computed/exited - unblocked. The first one is unblocked now. Picked up first task of the second chord - computed/exited - unblocked. One of the worker 1 or 3 picked up computed the second subtask of the chord, computed, exited. All three are ublocked now and the result is computed as expected. In general - this is a bad design - what I should do is 'create another subtask - that gets the result of the chords and if they are not successful yet, just retries after some time. The time between these retry intervals will allow the workers to finish individual sub tasks and then finally the callback of the main calling chord can be called.

edit 1 : Finally able to figure out how to deal with this - blocking in the tasks called by the outer chord was a bad idea. Instead what I did was - returned the AsyncResult from the called task 
and then created a poller task that polls for the results to be SUCCESS or FAILURE. And then calculate the result in this poller task. This task retries itself after a specific duration. (This is almost like unlock_chord task - just that I've done this myself in a separate task controlled by code - rather than let celery handle it)

Comment: sorry don't have it handy !!